# Can indexedDB work inside an iframe in Safari?

Tags: iframe, safari, indexeddb

I have an application that contains an iframe where I load an external website.

This website uses a indexedDB database to store some values. All works fine in Chrome, Firefox... but I have discovered this error when I try to open the app with Safari:

[image]

Could somebody tell me something about what is happening with Safari?

Regards

Comment: This sounds like the use-case for the [Storage Access API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage_Access_API).

Comment: @starball This is a snippet from the link you've pasted: "Note: The Storage Access API name may seem like somewhat of a misnomer, given that it only provides access to cookies, and not other client-side storage mechanisms such as Web Storage or IndexedDB. The name has been kept generic because it may provide access to other forms of client-side storage in the future."

You can't use it for IndexedDB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of now Safari does not support the usage of indexeddb when embedded in an iframe.
Apple says it is because of "security" :-(

Edit: this is only applicable to cross-origin. If the two urls are same origin the use of indexeddb works as expected.

And if you only use it internally perhaps you can: Go to Safari, enable developer tools (Preferences > Advanced) then Develop > Disable Cross-Origin Restrictions.
But this is only feasible if used internally.

The current state is a total mess.
In an iframe scenario you can only use localstorage (or sessionstorage) but that only gets you a storage for a few mb.

Or to go the old route and store everything on the server.